# Why this subset is not a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V = \mathbb{R}[x]$ the space of polynomial with real coeeficients
Let $U \subseteq V$ s.t $$U = \{p(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x] : \exists a,b \in \mathbb{R}, \; a\ne b \; s.t. \; p(a)=p(b)=0 \}.$$
Is $U$ is subspace of $V$?

According to my understanding $\mathbb{R}[x]$ means that $deg\leq 1$ so the only polynomial that has 2 different roots is the zero polynomial. so why is it not a subspace than?

Comment: Where did you get that definition of $\mathbb R [x]$?

Comment: No, the elements of $\mathbb{R}[x]$ can take any degree.

Comment: $x(x-1)$ and $x(x+1) \in U$ but their sum does not belong to $U$.

Comment: I assumed that, now I understand I was wrong. thank you for clarifying that for me.

Comment: By the way, I would like to understand why I got unvoted? I wrote the question and I also wrote how I tried to aprroached it. what was not ok here?

Comment: It's not me who unvoted. But, I think you should have included why this problem is important for you and would be interesting for others to work on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you understand @I H 's comment?  Your problem lies in your misunderstanding that $\mathbb{R}[x]$ only has polynomials of degree at most 1.  In fact, $\mathbb{R}[x]$ includes *all* polynomials [as this article describes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring).  Once you understand this, when you check the properties required for a subset of a vector space to be a subspace I think you will quickly find which property is not satisfied.  (You are correct in noticing that $U$ does contain the $0$ vector of $\mathbb{R}[x]$.)